# Could not Create Gmail Mailbox In Vtiger

Tags: gmail, sugarcrm, vtiger

I could't create mailbox with gmail in Vtiger CRM version 6.3.0. It alerted 'No route to host'.

[image]

Comment: try `ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465` as server  name

Answer (score 0):

This for those who are still facing the issue.

Now a days Google has updated his security and does not allow to login with normal password with IMAP or POP. Either you have to disable the security from your account or create a Application password which you have to use in 3rd Party App to login.

***How to generate an App password***

1. Visit your App passwords page. You may be asked to sign in to your Google Account.
2. At the bottom, click Select app and choose the app you’re using.
3. Click Select device and choose the device you’re using.
4. Select Generate.
5. Follow the instructions to enter the App password (the 16 character code in the yellow bar) on your device.
6. Select Done.

Once you are finished, you won’t see that App password code again. However, you will see a list of apps and devices you’ve created App passwords for.

Note: You may not be able to create an App password for less secure apps. Learn more about allowing less secure apps.

You can refer this link for more Details : https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

***How to allow Less Secure App login***

Change your settings to allow less secure apps to access your account. We don't recommend this option because it might make it easier for someone to break into your account. If you want to allow access anyway, follow these steps:

1. Go to the ["Less secure apps"](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) section in My Account.
2. Next to "Access for less secure apps," select Turn on. (Note to Google Apps users: This setting is hidden if your administrator has locked less secure app account access.)